# jquery accordion multi form in one page and when one form do not submit the other form remain lock

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, show-hide

I need to make some changes to this page: http://sirpaff.selgis.com/v1.1/CrearNuevaFichaFamiliar.php

As you can see there has a jQuery script,  this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

I need that when a user is inserting data into the form "Datos Generales y del Jefe(a) de Familia" 
the other Section of Accordion remain locked until the user completes the entire("Datos Generales y del Jefe(a) de Familia") form and give him to "Guardar"(submit).

Then, when save the information, is open the following next Section of Accordion "Carácteristica de la Vivienda"

Again similarly When fill the "Carácteristica de la Vivienda" section and click to the "Guardar" the following next section "Integrantes de la Familia" will be open.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this.

Firstly you need to handle form submission yourself : http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/09/09/intercept-a-form-submit-with-jquery-and-prevent-or-allow.aspx This prevents the page from reloading. You will need to send the data to the server yourself using an ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Secondly you want to disable accordion sections by intercepting beforeActivate:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({    
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
                          if ( ui.newHeader.text() === "Don&#39;tActivateMe" ){
                                 event.preventDefault();        
                           }    
                        }
 });
```

Comment: Not understanding. I am not well in jquery or javascript. can anyone give me the code how to be look like those two part(given by BASarat) or any other solution